# How avoid to register multiple network broadcast receivers?

Tags: android

I have a problem with the registration network broadcast receiver. As no one was using android 7.0 in this app it was all right because I declared this broadcast in the manifest. Right now, I must register broadcast receiver in my config activity after clicking save button. But when somebody clicked few times this button, then he registers a lot of network services. The problem is that the service must work in the background and intercept situations when the internet appears when the application is not open.

```
networkService = new NetworkService();
            if (!isReceiverRegistered(networkService)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    getActivity().registerReceiver(networkService, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
                    receivers.add(networkService);
                }
            }
```

Right now, I already have this broadcast receiver in Manifest and I already activate him after click on save button.

```
<receiver android:name=".services.NetworkService"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Create boolean that acts as flag '*that this receiver is registered*' so that the next time somebody clicks the same button, it wont register again, second approach is to disable the button (if that's acceptable in your usecase).

Comment: I'm not sure because when I put this boolean in this activity, then after recreating this activity boolean will be null or false. Maybe information about registration this receiver should be inserted into sharedPreferences, but I'm then I can not see if this is actually true because I have old value

Comment: you can use this boolean variable and save it in sharedPreferences.

Comment: So then, what if somebody kill instance of this app? This receiver should be killed, and I have in sharedPreferences value that this receiver is already registered

Comment: @Algeroth disable the button if its clicked button.setEnable(false) when already clicked.

Comment: I unfortunately  can not disable button because in this button I have more logic :(

Comment: You have already registered your receiver in manifest .So why you are you doing it at runtime ?  Although at runtime a single boolean will work for you . Cause receiver will only remains registered till its Started Component's lifeSpan .

Comment: @Algeroth you can create a new button for this and this will solve the problem..

Comment: @Algeroth dont use sharedpreference, remember that your listener is dependent to the Lifespan of your activity, in that case use `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: I'm doing it at runtime, because registration receiver in manifest not works on android 7.0

Comment: @Enzokie Okey, I will try using onRestoreInstanceState. I hope that it maybe solve this problem :) Thanks

Comment: @Algeroth onSaveInstanceState can temporarily keep your variable value when the device is rotated and that value must be explicitly restored in onCreate.

Comment: @Enzokie You're right. It's work only in specific case. But when I kill app then onRestoreInstance is not called. So I think that put it into sharedPreferences should be better option

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your broadcast off by default in manifest using the following code sample:--

```
<receiver android:name="name_of_your_receiver" android:enabled="false">

</receiver>
```

Then on button click execute the below code to enable the receiver:--

```
PackageManager pm  = context.getPackageManager();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, name_of_your_receiver.class);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```